# Why is ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT false?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

In `C++11` there is the `std::atomic_flag` that is useful for thread loops:

```
static std::atomic_flag s_done(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT);

void ThreadMain() {
    while (s_done.test_and_set()) {  // returns current value of s_done and sets to true
        // do some stuff in a thread
    }
}

// Later:
  s_done.clear();  // Sets s_done to false so the thread loop will drop out
```

The `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` sets the flag to `false` which means that the thread never gets in the loop.  A (bad) solution is possibly to do this:

```
void ThreadMain() {
    // Sets the flag to true but erases a possible false
    // which is bad as we may get into a deadlock
    s_done.test_and_set();
    while (s_done.test_and_set()) {
        // do some stuff in a thread
    }
}
```

The default constructor for `std::atomic_flag` specifies that the flag will be in an unspecified state.

Can I initialize the `atomic_flag` to `true`?  Is this the correct use of the `atomic_flag`?

Comment: You probably already know but it is possible to initialize `atomic<bool>` to `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Matt ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT doesn't set the flag to `false`, but initialises it to zero, which is the default for objects with static or thread local storage duration.

Comment: @Stefan "initialises it to zero" is that same as "set the flag to `false`", no?

Comment: @Matt it's the wrong wording, although 0 == false and semantically the same is reached, it is not correct. you want to initialize an object to zero and not to false.

Comment: @Stefan so what would you call `static bool s_bool = false;`?  Is that "initializing to `false`", "set to `false`" or "initialize to `0`"?  The only way I can see "set to `false`" and "initialize to `zero`" meaning different things if you had a system when `false` was an alias for a value where all the bits were not zero?

Comment: @MattClarkson yes you're right and that is exactly the reason why a defect report for the standard on this specific topic exists, concerning atomic_flag. (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1648.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always call `test_and_set` before starting the thread.

Comment: I have done that in my code but it feels strange and catches you out.  I was just wondering why it isn't possible to set the `atomic_flag` to `true` in initialization?

Comment: Because it's meant as a low-level primitive to build other primitives, and not for general use. `atomic<bool>` is where the money is.

Comment: OK, so I now understand that the `atomic_flag` is more used for spinlocks and not for signalling a thread to dump out of it's loop, guess that's what `std::atomic_bool` is for as you said @R.MartinhoFernandes.

Answer (score 4):

You are incorrectly using `atomic_flag` to implement a spinlock. The correct form would be:

```
static std::atomic_flag s_done(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT);

void ThreadMain() {
    while (s_done.test_and_set()) {  // returns current value of s_done and sets to true
        // spin while s_done is held by another thread
    }

    // do some stuff in a thread

    // Later:
    s_done.clear();  // Sets s_done to false so the thread loop will drop out
```

Although I recommend using an RAII holder so you can `return` or `throw` mid-function and the lock will be automatically released.

`ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` is `false` because the value of an `atomic_flag` is usually interpreted as indicating whether some resource is being held exclusively by a thread. At program start, there is no such thread, indeed the associated resource may not have even been initialized. So `false` would be the appropriate initial value.

As for intializing to `true`, the standard provides no guarantee that it's even possible to assign a boolean value to an `atomic_flag`.

Comment: I wasn't trying to implement a spinlock, I wait on a `condition_variable` inside the loop.  It's just to signify that the thread should exit.

Answer (score 2):

An atomic flag which is not initialized with `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` (or { 0 } ) is in an indeterminate state.

What you could do, to solve your problem is this:

```
std::atomic_flag lock = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
```

Now acquire the lock:

```
while (lock.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire))
    ; // ...
```

And release it afterwards:

```
lock.clear(std::memory_order_release);
```

This is what is called a `spin-lock`.