# What is ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT and how is it supposed to be used?

Tags: c++, c++17, atomic

Example code from [ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT)

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_flag static_flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT; // static initialization,
// guaranteed to be available during dynamic initialization of static objects.

int main()
{
    std::atomic_flag automatic_flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT; // guaranteed to work
//    std::atomic_flag another_flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT); // unspecified
}
```

Does this imply that relying on 'zero initialization' for example is unspecified ?
Are we supposed to always initialize using this define ? why ?

Comment: Have you read the page you linked? It's directly there: _the value held after any other initialization is unspecified_. The same statement in the Standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.flag#4.sentence-5.

Comment: @DanielLangr I did read it - which is why I ask

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17883703/580083.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thank you, that question is on the same topic - but OP there is just testing it wrong - not the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this imply that relying on *zero initialization* for example is unspecified?

You likely meant *value-initialization*, and the answer is yes, it is unspecified, as written in the Standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.flag#4.sentence-5.

> Are we supposed to always initialize using this define?

Yes. The sentence linked above implies that.

> Why?

Because the Standard demands it. As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17883703/580083), `std::atomic_flag` is not for general use, it's rather a low-level primitive for building other primitives.

For generic use, use `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: This almost answers my question. However "Because the Standard demands it" is not really a satisfying explaination.

Comment: But perhaps this should be asked in a seperate question.

Comment: @daurune It has been asked already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550947/why-atomic-flag-default-constructor-leaves-state-unspecified. This, in fact, makes your question a duplicate, so I would suggest to delete this one.